# Email sending error in ASP.NET using C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, email

This is the code for email sending, but it gives error in `try` block:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    EmailUtility email = new EmailUtility();
    email.Email = new MailMessage();
    string body = email.GetEmailTemplate(Server.MapPath("~/EmailTemplates"), "test.htm");
    EmailMessageToken token = new EmailMessageToken();
    token.TokenName = "$Name$";
    token.TokenValue = "Ricky";
    EmailMessageTokens tokens = new EmailMessageTokens();
    tokens.Add(token);
    //av.LinkedResources.Add(lr);
    email.Email.Body = email.ReplaceTokens(body, tokens);
    email.Email.To.Add(new MailAddress("sahil4659@gmail.com"));
    email.Email.IsBodyHtml = true;
    email.Email.From = new MailAddress("sahil4659@gmail.com");
    email.Email.Subject = "Hello from bootcamp";
    email.SMTP.Host = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SMTPServer"];
    try
    {
        email.SMTP.Send(email.Email);
        Response.Write("Email sent !");
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Response.Write(ex.StackTrace);
    }
}
```

The error is:

```
at System.Net.Mail.IisPickupDirectory.GetPickupDirectory()
at System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient.Send(MailMessage message)
at _Default.Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) in c:\Users\Sahil\Desktop\Csharp Email Code(2)\Test website\EmailTest.aspx.cs:line 38
```

Comment: Posting the full contents of the error (thats `ex.ToString()`) would improve the ability to answer this question infinately.

Comment: What is `EmailUtility`? Doesn't appear to be a framework class.

Comment: It looks like you're using a third party library. We need to know at least what you're using before we can help.

Comment: The type of the exception and it's message would be helpful too. Odds are that you have not set up SMTP correctly on your IIS.

Comment: @user459216: thanks for posting the exception text, but you missed the most important part of the exception, the message.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to read your mind and assume that you're seeing `System.Net.Mail.SmtpException: Cannot get IIS pickup directory.` Googling around, I see references to SMTP configuration you'll need in your web configuration.  Your mail server may require credentials, so you might need something like this:

```
<system.net>
    <mailSettings>
      <smtp from="fromaddress">
        <network defaultCredentials="true"
               host="smtpservername" port="smtpserverport" 
               userName="username" password="password"  />
      </smtp>
    </mailSettings>
</system.net>
```

... in your web.config. Essentially, configure your web app to be able to talk with the SMTP server.

See this thread for more [reference](http://www.eggheadcafe.com/community/aspnet/14/10119675/exception--cannot-get-iis-pickup-directory.aspx), and [here's relevant MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms164240.aspx).